# Entity Framework : Query with opposite condition in entity childs produce wrong results

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework.

I have this case :

```
 Partial Public Class Myobj
      Public Property id As Integer
      Public property name as string
      Public Overridable Property chld As ICollection(Of chld) = New HashSet(Of chld) 
   End Class


 Partial Public Class Myobj
     Public shared cond1 as DateTime
      <NotMapped> Public ReadOnly Property vls As integer
      Get
            Return chld.AsQueryable.Where(Function(t2) t2.date1<cond1).Select(Function(t3) t3.quantity).DefaultIfEmpty.Sum()
      End Get
End Property
End Class


Partial Public Class chld
    Public Property id As Integer
    Public Property date1 as DateTime
    Public Property quantity as Integer
    Public Property ParentID as integer
    Public Overridable Property MyObj1 As MyObj
End Class
```

Now on my form, I have this code :

```
Dim dt1 as DateTime=CDate("08/08/2014")
Myobj.cond1=dt1

 Dim list1 = (From t In context.MyObj Select New With { _
      .Parent = t, _
      .chl =  (From t2 In t.chld.AsQueryable.Where(Function(t3) t3.Date1>=dt1) Select t2) 
}).ToList
```

As you can see, on Not mapped property `vls` is calculated the sum of child's quantity before date "08/08/2014".

On the main query are selected the children with date after the date "08/08/2014"

This query always produces 0 in `vls` property for each item in Myobj1.( !! but it's not true according to data in database!!).

Why this query product a such result?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tell, but you have lazy loading disabled. This means that after the query has ended, the `MyObj` entities only have `chld` objects >= "08/08/2014" in their `chld` collections. Entity Framework populates these collections by *relationship fixup*.

So if you access `MyObj.vls`, there are no `chld`'s < "08/08/2014". With lazy loading enabled (and the context still in scope) this would trigger lading the full `chld` collection and you'd get the required results.

However, it's more efficient to query the `MyObj` entities with `chld` included and do the processing afterwards in memory.

Comment: Yes . lazyloading is disabled , but the query that calculate the sum's isn't executed during the execution of the main  query ? Because if  I have a identical sum query outside the class , inside the projection for example : .sumvl={the same query as inside the class} the result will be correct. Why the query inside the partial class doesn't show the correct results ?

Comment: Of course it isn't. The property `vls` is not mapped.

Comment: But all objects MyObj1 that are selected , contain this Not mapped Property , so why the .vls don't get value ?  So when a not mapped property get value ?

Comment: Did you understand my explanation? Which `chld` objects do the `MyObj` entities contain after the `ToList()`?

Comment: ok , but why if I remove from the projections the part : .chl=.......... , and with lazyloading disabled , all the sum are calculated correctly. So following your logic , each Myobj object will not contain any chld object after the tolist ?

Comment: No, unless you `Include()` them. Without lazy loading, only selecting `MyObj`, you can't possibly have any loaded `chld` collections. Unless there are still `chld` objects in the cache from previous queries.

Comment: No , I have no include. And besides the case I mention above , is another case that works :  Dim list1 = (From t In context.MyObj Select New With { _
      .Parent = t, _
      .chl =  (From t2 In t.chld.AsQueryable.Where(Function(t3) t3.Date1>=dt1) Select t2), _
      .sum1 =(From t2 in t.chld.AsQueryable.Where(Function(t2) t2.date1<cond1).Select(Function(t3) t3.quantity).DefaultIfEmpty
}).ToList     , so the same query but outside the partial class.

Comment: Yes of course this works! It's one query, it all happens in SQL. After the `ToList` everything is over and done with. No lazy loading required or whatever. You just don't seem to grasp the concepts of EF expressions and the segregation between database and client-side processing. Maybe you should look at generated SQL more often. And this is the last thing I say here. You keep discussing with people, always slightly changing the case. I answered your question. *Many* others answered your daily questions. Meanwhile you never upvote or accept an answer, because you keep demanding more more more.

Comment: And why the query inside the partial class doesn't happen in SQL but after the ToList?  ( I'm not quering different things , I want to better understand. It's true,  I have changed several questions , but I doesn't change this questions for what we are talking now.)